# Simple node.js app deployed to Bluemix seems to be leaking memory

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, ibm-cloud

I am learning node.js, and have a fairly simple application which seems to be leaking memory when deployed to Bluemix. I need assistance in determining if this is caused by my code, or a module I am using.

When deployed with the Monitoring and Cloudant services it would crash with an out of memory error, and be restarted by Bluemix every 12-14 hours - with 256 megs of RAM.  I upped the RAM to 1 gig and it still occurs (although less frequently).

When I deploy the app to Bluemix and issue calls to the / route I can see the memory climb slowly up.  When testing locally in windows, I do not see the same behavior (testing via process explorer and seeing the amount of private bytes & working set)

I have simplified my app (and removed the monitoring service) and can still reproduce, though the increase is slower with the simplified app.

```
/*jshint node:true*/

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// app.js - Middleware routing
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// This application uses express as it's web server
// for more info, see: http://expressjs.com
var express = require( 'express' );

// For handling the POST bodies and multi-part bodies0
var bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' );
var multer = require( 'multer' );

// Create a new express server
var app = express();

// Get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var cfenv = require( 'cfenv' );
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// Catch all handlers for unhandled URLs
//
app.post( '/*', function( req, res ){
    logRequest( req );
    res.send( 'Unhandled POST received' );
});

app.get( '/*', function( req, res ){
    logRequest( req );
    res.send( 'Unhandled GET received' );
});


// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, appEnv.bind, function() {

    // print a message when the server starts listening
  console.log("server starting on -- " + appEnv.url);
});

function logRequest(req){
    console.log("Received,"+new Date().toLocaleString()+","+req.method+","+req.originalUrl);
}
```

Here is the data I gathered, memory is listed in Megs, and I issued requests to the / route:

- 83.1M on startup
- 83.5M after 1 call to /
- 83.5M after 5 more calls to /
- 83.6 after 5 more calls to /
- 84.2 after 20 more calls to /
- 85.1 after 10 more calls to /
- 86.6 after 20 more calls to /

I tried using the heapdump module, but it fails when being deployed to Bluemix.

**cf-node-debug installation now successful - see bottom of question**
Installed cf-node-debug as suggested, in package.json specified:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/cf-node-debug app.js"
  },
```

When I pushed the app I got the following:

```
T13:19:44.08-0400 [STG/39]     OUT -----> Downloaded app package (36K)
T13:19:44.46-0400 [STG/39]     OUT -----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (2.6M)
T13:19:44.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT     -----> Node.js Buildpack Version: v1.18-20150519-1759
T13:19:44.85-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Resetting git environment
T13:19:45.35-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        TIP: Specify a node version in package.json
T13:19:45.35-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Defaulting to latest stable node: 0.12.2
T13:19:45.35-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Installing IBM SDK for Node.js from cache
T13:19:45.78-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Checking and configuring service extensions
T13:19:45.95-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Restoring node_modules directory from cache
T13:19:46.21-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Pruning cached dependencies not specified in package.json
T13:19:47.22-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Installing dependencies
T13:19:54.50-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        > ws@0.4.32 install /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/cf-node-debug/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/ws
T13:19:54.50-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
T13:20:04.31-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        make: Entering directory `/tmp/staged/app/node_modules/cf-node-debug/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/ws/build'
T13:20:04.32-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
T13:20:04.71-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
T13:20:04.76-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished
T13:20:04.77-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          COPY Release/bufferutil.node
T13:20:04.78-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
T13:20:05.15-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
T13:20:05.21-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
T13:20:05.21-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          COPY Release/validation.node
T13:20:05.24-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        make: Leaving directory `/tmp/staged/app/node_modules/cf-node-debug/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/ws/build'
T13:20:05.29-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        npm WARN deprecated static-favicon@1.0.2: use serve-favicon module
T13:20:05.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        cf-node-debug@0.1.2 node_modules/cf-node-debug
T13:20:05.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── underscore@1.6.0
T13:20:05.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── q@1.0.1
T13:20:05.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── passport-local@1.0.0 (passport-strategy@1.0.0)
T13:20:05.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── nopt@2.2.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
T13:20:05.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── passport@0.2.2 (pause@0.0.1, passport-strategy@1.0.0)
T13:20:05.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── client-sessions@0.6.0 (cookies@0.3.8)
T13:20:05.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── http-proxy@1.1.6 (eventemitter3@1.1.0)
T13:20:05.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── body-parser@1.3.1 (raw-body@1.1.6, qs@0.6.6, bytes@1.0.0, type-is@1.2.1)
T13:20:05.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── express@4.4.5 (parseurl@1.0.1, utils-merge@1.0.0, merge-descriptors@0.0.2, cookie@0.1.2, escape-html@1.0.1, qs@0.6.6, cookie-signature@1.
@1.0.0, fresh@0.2.2, vary@0.1.0, methods@1.0.1, serve-static@1.2.3, buffer-crc32@0.2.3, path-to-regexp@0.1.2, type-is@1.2.1, accepts@1.0.7, proxy-addr@1.0.1, debug@1.0.2, send@0.4.3)
T13:20:05.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── cfenv@0.2.0 (ports@1.1.0, js-yaml@3.0.2)
T13:20:05.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── handlebars@2.0.0 (optimist@0.3.7, uglify-js@2.3.6)
T13:20:05.80-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        └── node-inspector@0.7.3 (opener@1.3.0, debug@0.8.1, which@1.0.9, async@0.4.1, strong-data-uri@0.1.1, yargs@1.1.3, rc@0.3.5, glob@3.2.11, exp
4.32)
T13:20:06.02-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Caching node_modules directory for future builds
T13:20:06.59-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Cleaning up node-gyp and npm artifacts
T13:20:06.60-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> No Procfile found; Adding npm start to new Procfile
T13:20:06.60-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Building runtime environment
T13:20:06.60-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Checking and configuring service extensions
T13:20:06.85-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Installing App Management
T13:20:06.90-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> WARN: App Management (Development Mode) cannot be installed because the start script cannot be found.
T13:20:06.91-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        TIP: Specify your start script in 'package.json' or 'Procfile'.
T13:20:06.92-0400 [STG/0]      ERR
T13:20:11.28-0400 [STG/39]     OUT -----> Uploading droplet (20M)
T13:20:20.47-0400 [DEA/39]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 1dde346e-4e51-407f-af7b-607772826e72
T13:20:32.91-0400 [App/0]      OUT
T13:20:32.91-0400 [App/0]      OUT > NodejsStarterApp@0.0.1 start /home/vcap/app
T13:20:32.91-0400 [App/0]      OUT > cf-node-debug app.js
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR     util.js:634
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR   ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR                                           ^
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR     at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:634:43)
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/cf-node-debug/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/index.js:106:17)
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR     at require (module.js:384:17)
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/cf-node-debug/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy.js:4:17)
T13:20:33.38-0400 [App/0]      ERR     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
T13:20:33.40-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-39-generic
T13:20:33.40-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
T13:20:33.40-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! node v0.12.2
T13:20:33.40-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
T13:20:33.40-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
T13:20:33.40-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! NodejsStarterApp@0.0.1 start: `cf-node-debug app.js`
T13:20:33.40-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Exit status 1
T13:20:33.40-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!
T13:20:33.40-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Failed at the NodejsStarterApp@0.0.1 start script 'cf-node-debug app.js'.
T13:20:33.41-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the NodejsStarterApp package,
T13:20:33.41-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! not with npm itself.
T13:20:33.41-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
T13:20:33.41-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     cf-node-debug app.js
T13:20:33.41-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! You can get their info via:
T13:20:33.41-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     npm owner ls NodejsStarterApp
T13:20:33.41-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
T13:20:33.41-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
T13:20:33.41-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
T13:20:33.47-0400 [DEA/39]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections


$ npm --version
1.4.28  
$ node --version  
v0.10.33
```

Looks like http-proxy@1.1.6 (eventemitter3@1.1.0)

Note: Using SDK for Node.js from IBM

At Jack's suggestion I tried specifying the engine like:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "2.7.4"
  },
```

The staging reported:

```
2015-06-04T14:27:41.87-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Resetting git environment
2015-06-04T14:27:42.31-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Requested node range:  0.10.x
2015-06-04T14:27:42.31-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Resolved node version: 0.10.38
2015-06-04T14:27:42.31-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Installing IBM SDK for Node.js from cache
```

but I obtained the same error as before:

```
2015-06-04T14:28:12.89-0400 [App/0]      ERR util.js:556
2015-06-04T14:28:12.89-0400 [App/0]      ERR   ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
2015-06-04T14:28:12.89-0400 [App/0]      ERR                                           ^
2015-06-04T14:28:12.89-0400 [App/0]      ERR TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

**Update 3:35pm EST**

I forked [cf-node-debug](https://github.com/retinaburn/cf-node-debug) and modified the http-proxy to 1.11.x. I updated package.json to:

```
"cf-node-debug": "git://github.com/retinaburn/cf-node-debug.git",
```

I pushed the app, and now have access to the debug console, but there does not seem to be any heap dumps that I can use to investigate memory leaks.

Comment: Can you remove the Monitoring service, restage your application, and try again?

Comment: Hi Ram, for the simplified app above the monitoring service was removed already.

Comment: Can you deploy the following package to help you access heap profiling tools? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cf-node-debug

Comment: Hi James, tried.  Error when starting up. Not sure what is wrong now.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you specify the engine version to be 0.10.x to see whether the problem still exists?

Comment: Hi Jack-Junjie, I am not sure I understood your request, but I took a crack at it.  Updated the question, same error (if I did it correctly).

Comment: I forked cf-node-debug and changed the http-version to 1.11.x and locally it seems a little healthier, it gets past the error.  Now I have to try and rebind the service.

Comment: Could you try pushing your app with the following command? `cf push myappname -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack.git`

Comment: Have there been any new updates on this issue? I'm experiencing the same thing, no apparent memory leak in development but once on Bluemix the memory usage steadily climbs until it crashes. Even without any usage, just uptime monitoring.

Comment: What is your limit set at?  I found that the initial RAM level (256 mb) was too low. Once I increased it (512 mb) and ran a load test I saw it increase until some sort of maximum was released it levelled off.

Comment: @Craig It's 512mb, however Bluemix I believe runs my application at 64bit, the default memory allocation for node on 64bit systems is 1gb. I am setting memory to 512mb in my manifest file, but perhaps that is being ignored. I'll try ramping my available memory and see if I experience the same leveling off effect you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that the specified sample app does perform garbage collection in Bluemix with the memory set to 1gb.

I tested using [apache bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) with 1000 requests to '/' with 10 concurrent transactions.

I suspect the earlier volume tests were too low to trigger a gc.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to isolate your issues. Does this behavior occurs when you are running the application locally?
There is a good node-module memwatch that may help.
I think memwatch works with node.js 10.x
There is a memwatch-next that will work with node.js 0.12.x.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that it does not occur locally. I will check out memwatch-next.  Thanks.